# SVN missing revision - Has anybody got a solution

Tags: svn

Hello everybody and I hope you're having a good day!

I have a small problem which I've searched for a solution to no avail. Maybe somebody here could help me? The problem is this:

I am using a script I wrote which loops through all the folders and performs a hotcopy of the repos to a network location. All works really well apart from one repo, which fails with the following error:

svnadmin: Can't open file 'E:\repositories\20100831_repository_xyz\db\revs\0\235': The system cannot find the file specified.
Unable to backup the repository.
<==ERROR SEGMENT COMPLETE==!>

I dont mind losing the revision, but I obviously cant export and import (losing all revisions). Also, I really need to get it fixed as its breaking my nightly backups! 500gb's used in 4 weeks...

Anybody have a working solution?

Comment: Dump is worthless with large repos .. It's impossible to dump in a reasonable amount of time. I do similar hot copy and also maintain svnsync to a mirror. I do have a new problem though svnsync decided to skip several revs for a particular file. We switched to the mirror but the first commit to that file now caused a baseline mismatch .. I believe it's gotta be a bug with svnsync .. Anyone experience having this issue? I'm in the middle of trying to fix the missing revs.. Ill post my fix..

Answer (score 2):

First of all you're better off using [`svnadmin dump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) as it will package each repo with
its' meta-data - revisions, chagnes, users, etc. Your "down-and-dirty" method is risky because there is the possibility to lose some files while transfering them over the network. Then you can safely transport all the repos
over Intranet, Internet or whatever and load them in another SVN instance or just keep the files.

This is how the command works:

```
svnadmin dump REPOSITORY_NAME > out_file.dump
```

What I use is a cronjob that scans my svn_root directory with `ls -1`, that's where all the root Repo dirs are, for all directories (except ./ and ../) gets their names and performs a repository dump on each of them. After that is done I safely move the files to another server via ssh.

And another thing - if you want to have another server that is working (as a slave/mirror) and up to date you can use repository hooks to sync it with the master. Drop a comment on this if you would like me to explain that. It is not hard at all.